# Issue in parsing Json using JsonObject

Tags: json, gson

I am facing issue while parsing the `JsonResponse`. Getting error

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1
```

**Actual API Response**

```
["fa0d30bf-49ad-47be-a840-34393493hdkjfd"]
```

I need to extract the value out of this array. Below is the code that I've tried.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = "["fa0d30bf-49ad-47be-a840-34393493hdkjfd"]"
String gsonString = gson.toJson(jsonString);
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(gsonString);
String api = arr.getJSONObject(indexOfArray).toString(); // indexOfArray = 0
```

Could someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gson, you can try below code

```
String jsonString = "[\"fa0d30bf-49ad-47be-a840-34393493hdkjfd\"]";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray arr = gson.fromJson (jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray(); //Converts the response string to JsonArray

String api = arr.get(indexOfArray).getAsString(); // indexOfArray = 0
```